# Questions with accepted answers cramp my style

Tags: bug, design, meta

The styling for the accepted answer box seems...not right:

[image: accepted answer box]

Look at how cramped that poor 44 is! Assuming that's not intentional, it seems like the expected styling would actually be:

```css
.cp {
    /* remove margin-top: 7px; */
}

/* ..or .cp > div but I'm assuming this is LESSed-in */
.cp .votes, .cp .status, .cp .views {
    padding: 10px 5px 6px 5px;
}
```

which gives us a little more breathing room:

[image: fixed styling]

Comment: +1 for the little frowny face you got your toddler to add. Sweet. :)